# How to return reverse array with explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

So explode functions breaks a string into arrays like this:

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
```

And the result would be:

```
Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => world. [2] => It's [3] => a [4] => beautiful [5] => day. )
```

But what if we need to sort the array in reverse, so the expected result would be looked like this:

```
Array ( [0] => day [1] => beautiful [2] => a  [3] => It's [4] => world. [5] => Hello  )
```

So how to do this with explode function?

Comment: You can use `array_reverse`. So `array_reverse(explode(" ",$str));`. Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: _diversely_ is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_reverse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) like this for your desired output:

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
var_dump(array_reverse(explode(" ",$str)));

// Output
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "day."
  [1]=>
  string(9) "beautiful"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "It's"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "world."
  [5]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
}
```